Issue regarding publishing topic to confluent cloud
So, we have made a free subscription from Azure to confluent cloud for POC. We previously had done POC on free tier through email, it worked without any issue. Now we are having an error while publishing topic in Confluent Cloud broker. We are able to fetch details regarding cluster and topics but when we try to publish its giving error.
[INFO ] 2024-07-30 08:25:00.632 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] network.Selector - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Failed authentication with pkc-7prvp.centralindia.azure.confluent.cloud/20.198.110.25 (channelId=-1) (SSL handshake failed)
[INFO ] 2024-07-30 08:25:00.633 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Node -1 disconnected.
[ERROR] 2024-07-30 08:25:00.633 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Connection to node -1 (pkc-7prvp.centralindia.azure.confluent.cloud/20.198.110.25:443) failed authentication due to: SSL handshake failed
[WARN ] 2024-07-30 08:25:00.633 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-2] clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-2] Bootstrap broker pkc-7prvp.centralindia.azure.confluent.cloud:443 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
[ERROR] 2024-07-30 08:25:00.634 [https-jsse-nio-9970-exec-1] service.KafkaService - org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

We have not configured any SSL properties, we are using a truststore and keystore for java services but not provided it in properties for Kafka. Bootstrap URL is able to ping with telnet but not accessible when used in chrome so cannot get the browser cert.
Please do tell if there is any information needed or anyone faced this issue
We are expecting to publish a message to Confluent cloud bootstrap URL through our Java service but are getting SSL handshake error

I’m voting to close this question because Confluent Support has their own methods of contact
